# Query Transaction Started but never Ends

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I run a query sometimes and it just hangs.  I go look at processes in the Activity Monitor (SQL Server 2008 R2) and it shows it and just that the transaction is open and it hoses the entire server.

This makes no sense, even if this was a long running query it should at some point time out one would assume.

I do a trace on it and it shows this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us the query that you run ?

Comment: It might be an explicitly started transaction which encountered an error and was never committed nor rolled back.

Comment: If your query has BEGIN TRANSACTION then that transaction stays open long after the query has finished - actually until you commit, rollback, or it gets committed/rolled back for you. We need more details to help you determine the problem.

Comment: so I should do what in my query to commit and rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
GO
```

Forgetful Fred has opened a transaction and went to lunch. There is nothing to timeout as there is no request active. The user must explcitly commit or rollback, eventually. An adminsitrator can forcefully terminate the offending session using [`KILL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx). Such a session/transaction can stay open for *years* if left on its own devices (assuming you doin't run out of log and you don't restart the server).

More convoluted scenarios can occur even when the user *did* issue a COMMIT, if distributed transactions are involved, see [How It Works: Orphan DTC Transaction (Session/SPID = -2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/04/20/how-it-works-orphan-dtc-transaction-session-spid-2.aspx).

Comment: when I try to kill the process I get The Activity Monitor is unable to execute queries against server CORP-SQL08DV,40001. Activity Monitor for this instance will be placed into a paused state. Use the context menu in the overview pane to resume the Activity Monitor.

Comment: there's a remaining process we can't stop going against the tempdb database, something about SET @is_policy_automation_enabled  = (SELECT CONVERT(bit, current_value).  This query is running forever and seems to be hosing everything.
                                              FROM msdb.dbo.syspolicy_configuration
                                              WHERE name = 'Enabled')